# print difference line number and column number for tab separeated files in linux

Tags: linux

how can I print difference line number and column number for tab separated files in linux

example- compare File 1 vs File2 and print line no. for difference record and column no of difference present in file2.

In file1:

```
User_ID   First_name    Last_name   Address                     Postal_code 

User_1    fistname      Lastname    35, Park Lake, California           32068

user2     Johnny        Depp        32, Park Lake, California           

user3     Tom           Cruise      5322 Otter Lane Middleberge         32907

user4     Leonardo      DiCaprio    Half-Way Pond, Georgetown           1230

user5   Sylvester       Stallone    6762,33 Ave N,St. Petersburg        33710
```

and

In file2:

```
User_ID   First_name    Last_name   Address                     Postal_code 

User_1    fistname      Lastname    35, Park Lake, California           32068

user2     Johnny        Depp        32, NEW Street, California          96206

user30    Tom           Cruise      5322 Otter Lane Middleberge         32907

user4     Leonardo      DiCaprio'   Half-Way Pond, Georgetown           00000

user5     Sylvester     Stallone    6762,33 Ave N,St. Petersburg        33710

user6     Nicolas           Cage                                        55010
```

expected result:- difference in file2 is for line number followed by column number-

```
3 COLUMN NO- 4,5

4 COLUMN NO-1 

5 COLUMN NO 3,5

6 COLUNN NO 5

7 COLUMN NO 1,2,3,4,5
```

**Note**: File size to be compare is in GB and File is tab separated and has more than 400 tab separated column.

Currently I am using Awk command for printing the line number but i am not able to get column no. 
Can we loop the awk or have nested awk

Current command using-

```
awk 'NR==FNR{Arr[$0]++;next}!($0 in Arr){print FNR}' file1 file2
```

Comment: It iss not duplicate I want column no. along with line number for difference record